# can't add foreign key for table that has files

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm building a project with angular and php, I added to my database table "file" that I can send files to him and retrieve all files information. now I'm trying to add a foreign key("Customer_id") from "Customers" table to connect the customer to specific file.

But when I try to add a relation it says:

> error relational features are disabled

Can any one please help?can it be that the problem because the table has files?

This is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE `file` (
    `id`        Int Unsigned Not Null Auto_Increment,
    `name`      VarChar(255) Not Null Default 'Untitled.txt',
    `mime`      VarChar(50) Not Null Default 'text/plain',
    `size`      BigInt Unsigned Not Null Default 0,
    `data`      MediumBlob Not Null,
    `created`   DateTime Not Null,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: are u talkink abt sql tables?

Comment: Also this error is well known in the phpMyAdmin community. Are you using it?

Comment: @Iceman yes I'm using phpmyadmin what should I do?

Comment: @Iceman do you need the code I'm using? I can edit the question

Comment: yes, please do so..

Comment: @Iceman can you please check now?

Comment: which is throwing the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120349/discussion-between-tanyaa-and-iceman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the engines used in both of the tables are `innoDB`.

As you mentioned in chat, your `files` table was `MyISAM`, hence the Foreign Constraints were disabled!!.